# How do I index an array of multi-part fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I will have type that has an ARRAY of a multi-part field.
the data in that field will look like this:

```
grp type num
111 ABC 112233445566
123 DEF 192898048901
222 ABC 180920948012
333 XWZ 112233445566
```

I want to be search on just num to find my document.
I also want to be able to search on type and num to find my doc.
optionally include all three: grp=111 type=ABC num=112233445566

What I dont want is cross-matching of these compound values..
IE, type=XWZ and num=192898048901  would be a false hit

So do I implement these as multi_fields with a custom tokenizer?
(which presumably would concantenate to create the three key types)

Or can compound word tokenfilter or some other technique help me accomplish this.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can index combinations as additional fields:

```
"doc" : {
    "properties" : {
...
        "array_type" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
                "grp" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
                "type" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
                "num" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed"" },
                "type_num" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
                "grp_type_num" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
                }
            },
...
    }
}
```

When querying, use the field that matches the info you have.  For example, to search for type and num, you could write a query like this:

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": {
              "type_num": "XWZ 112233445566"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I found an easier way... Key is that I just need to be able to search by the three possible combinations... dont really need to directly reference grp typ or num.

Path_analyer is doing just what I want:

```
# Create a new index with custom path_hierarchy analyzer 
# See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/accts-test" -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "accts-analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "accts-tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "accts-tokenizer": {
                    "type": "path_hierarchy",
                    "delimiter": "-",
                    "reverse": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
          "_timestamp" : {
            "enabled" : true,
            "store" : true
          }
        },
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "name": { "type": "string"},
                "accts": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_name": "acct",
                    "index_analyzer": "accts-analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "keyword"
               }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Then Testing it via _analyzer endpoint shows this:

```
# curious about path analyzer? test it:
echo testing analyzier
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/accts-test/_analyze?analyzer=accts-analyzer&pretty=1' -d '111-BBB-2233445566'
echo
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "111-BBB-2233445566",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 18,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "BBB-2233445566",
    "start_offset" : 4,
    "end_offset" : 18,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "2233445566",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 18,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```